# Which complexity is better?

Tags: algorithm, graph, big-o, complexity-theory

Assume that a graph has `N` nodes and `M` edges, and the total number of iterations is `k`.
(`k` is a constant integer, larger than 1, independent of `N` and `M`)

Let `D=M/N` be the average degree of the graph.

I have two graph-based iterative search algorithms.
The first algorithm has the complexity of `O(D^{2k})` time.
The second algorithm has the complexity of `O(k*D*N)` time.

Based on their Big `O` time complexity, which one is better?

Some told me that the first one is better because the number of nodes `N` in a graph is usually much larger than `D` in real world.

Others said that the second one is better because `k` is exponentially increased for the first one, but is linearly increased for the second one.

Comment: Do you have anything else to say about `k`? Does it depend on `N`, `M` or anything else? Is it a constant? Is it greater than 1?

Comment: Is `k` a parameter of the algorithms or part of the input?

Comment: An algorithm that dynamically decides between your two algorithms will be no worse than either of them.

Comment: The iteration number k is given as an input parameter of the algorithm.

Comment: What is small `d`? is it the same as big `D`?

Comment: @anatolyg, `k` is independent of `N`, `M`, k is the given iteration number (`k` can be regarded as a constant).

Comment: @sds, sorry. `d` is actually `D`. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 3):

### Summary

Neither of your two `O`'s dominate the other, so the right approach is to chose the algorithm based on the inputs

### `O` Domination

1. The first it better when `D<1` (sparse graphs) and similar.
2. The second is better when `D` is relatively large

### Algorithm Selection

The important parameter is not just the `O` but the actual constant in front of it.
E.g., an `O(n)` algorithm which is actually `100000*n` is *worse* than `O(n^2)` which is just `n^2` when `n<100000`.

So, given the graph and the desired iteration count `k`, you need to estimate the expected performance of each algorithm and chose the best one.

Answer (score 2):

Big-O notation describes how a function *grows*, when its arguments grow. So if you want to estimate growth of algorithm time consumption, you should estimate first how D and N will grow. That requires some additional information from your domain.

If we assume that `N` is going to grow anyway. For `D` you have several choices:

1. `D` remains constant - the first algorithm is definitely better
2. `D` grows proportionally to `N` - the second algorithm is better

More generally: if `D` grows faster than `N^(1/(2k-1))`, you should select the first algorithm, otherwise - the second one.

Answer (score 0):

For every fixed D, D^(2k) is a constant, so the first algorithm will beat the second if M is large enough. However, what is large enough depends on D. If D isn't constant or limited, the two complexities cannot be compared.

In practice, you would implement both algorithms, find a good approximation for their actual speed, and depending on your values pick the one that will be faster.